# Exception while deleting cookies with Safari 10 / Selenium 3.0.1

Tags: java, macos, selenium, safari, safaridriver

I'm having a problem adding and deleting cookies with the native SafariDriver in Safari 10.0: A generic `WebDriverException` is thrown and I'm looking for a fix or a workaround.

This is occurring with the following components:

- Mac OS X 10.11.6 (El Capitan)
- Safari 10.0 [provides *native* implementation of SafariDriver]
- Selenium 3.0.1

The following [document](https://webkit.org/blog/6900/webdriver-support-in-safari-10/) indicates that the native SafariDriver in Safari 10 no longer requires installation of the Selenium SafariDriver *extension*, but depends on Selenium 3.0 or higher. And I've ensured that Selenium 3.x is being used and that Selenium 2.x is not on my system.

While testing, the browser window has the orange SmartSearch field, and throws the exception below when clicking the test window. I *know* the test framework is using the correct audio driver because of the following system property,and the fact that the exception thrown indicates the Selenium version as 3.0.1

The `webdriver.safari.driver` Mac OS X *system property* is set to `/usr/bin/safaridriver`

The following works with Safari:

```
            driver.manage().getCookies();
```

The following fails with Safari, but works with Chrome

```
            driver.manage().addCookie(cookie);
            driver.manage().deleteAllCookies();
```

Exception stack trace for `addCookie()`

> <sup>DEBUG [main] (DefaultNavigator.java:201) - Caught exception:
>   org.openqa.selenium.WebDriverException: An unknown server-side error
>   occurred while processing the command. (WARNING: The server did not
>   provide any stacktrace information) Command duration or timeout: 4
>   milliseconds</sup>
>
> <sup>Build info: version: '3.0.1', revision: '1969d75',</sup>
>
> <sup>time:'2016-10-18 09:49:13 -0700' System info: host: 'L-C02S61GDxxxx', ip:
>   '192.168.47.xxx, os.name: 'Mac OS X', os.arch: 'x86_64', os.version:
>   '10.11.6', java.version: '1.8.0_112</sup>
>
> <sup>Driver info:
>   org.openqa.selenium.safari.SafariDriver Capabilities
>   [{applicationCacheEnabled=true, rotatable=false, databaseEnabled=true,
>   handlesAlerts=true, version=11602.3.12.0.1, cleanSession=true,
>   platform=MAC, nativeEvents=true, locationContextEnabled=false,
>   webStorageEnabled=true, browserName=safari, javascriptEnabled=true,
>   cssSelectorsEnabled=true}] Session ID:
>   7513DEE7-DB0F-4CBD-B21E-D760C69880DB</sup>
>
> <sup>DEBUG [main] (AbstractTest.java:91) - ###### Executing test: testSignInSuccess
>                   at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
>                   at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
>                   at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
>                   at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423)
>                   at org.openqa.selenium.remote.ErrorHandler.createThrowable(ErrorHandler.java:216)
>                   at org.openqa.selenium.remote.ErrorHandler.throwIfResponseFailed(ErrorHandler.java:168)
>                   at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.execute(RemoteWebDriver.java:635)
>                   at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver$RemoteWebDriverOptions.addCookie(RemoteWebDriver.java:718)
>                   ...
>                   at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
>                   at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
>                   at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
>                   at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423)
>                   at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.createTest(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:217)
>                   at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner$1.runReflectiveCall(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:266)
>                   at org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:12)
>                   at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.methodBlock(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:263)
>                   at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:78)
>                   at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:57)
>                   at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:290)
>                   at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:71)
>                   at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:288)
>                   at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:58)
>                   at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:268)
>                   at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:363)
>                   at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit4.runner.JUnit4TestReference.run(JUnit4TestReference.java:86)
>                   at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.TestExecution.run(TestExecution.java:38)
>                   at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:459)
>                   at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:678)
>                   at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.run(RemoteTestRunner.java:382)
>                   at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.main(RemoteTestRunner.java:192)</sup>

Comment: Did you try running the tests in Safari Technology Preview? It might have been fixed there.

Answer (score 0):

This was a known issue in safaridriver. It is fixed in Safari 11.